# como acceder al texto para ser iterado desde el dom de un input con label, el texto esta en el label, para un checkbox

Tags: dom, input, label

Este es el `html`:

```
<template  id="clone>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="novel">
    <label    for="category">Food Fair</label>
</template>
```

y este el código `js`:

```
function checkboxesrender(categorias){
    let lista = document.querySelector('.checkbox')
    let clone = document.querySelector('#clone').content
    let novel = document.querySelector('#novel')
    console.log(lista);
      //console.log(clone.document.querySelector('label'));
    for (const iterator of categorias) {
        let impostor = clone.cloneNode(true)
        lista.appendChild(impostor)
    }
}
```

La idea es que cada `checkbox` tenga la categoría correspondiente en el texto del `label`, que es lo que se va a visualizar.

Answer (score 0):

Cabe destacar primero que no se puede acceder a los elementos dentro de una etiqueta `template` directamente desde el objeto `document`. Dicho esto, esta linea de código no funciona como se espera

`let novel = document.querySelector('#novel')`

ademas de que no está siendo usada esa variable.

De acuerdo a tu pregunta y suponiendo que `categorias` es un arreglo de strings, puedes hacer esto:

```
function checkboxesrender(categorias){
    let lista = document.querySelector('.checkbox')
    let clone = document.querySelector('#clone').content

    for (let categoria of categorias) {
        let impostor = clone.cloneNode(true)
        impostor.querySelector('label').innerText = categoria
        lista.appendChild(impostor)
    }
}
```

cualquier duda solo invócame ;)